# Multiple services logging - best practice

Tags: c#, logging

My system contains lots of components: Windows service, Web services and Web site, all of them are written in C#. Currently, all the components are logging to a DB with NLog using a wrapper DLL, and each one holds a separate config file for it (which pretty much are the same).

I'd like to unite all the config file to a single global config for NLog. What will be the best way to get the global config from each component? a single global file? a config provider service?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement (though not with NLog specifically). I had a system with 7 different services running, and each needed to log activity for later reporting.

My solution: I created an 8th component...a monitor. Along with this I used XML serialization in the other 7 services. They would serialize XML "packets" to disk, in a known location, which the monitor would periodically sweep. On sweep it would collect the packets, deserialize them, and generate the official log file in order of datetime.

Another option I am researching is making use of named pipes to communicate directly with the monitor, avoiding the file I/O and all the attendant problems associated with it.